# How can I display conformal mapping?

Tags: plotting, complex, latex

`z` to quadratic function with conformal map. How to plot this in Wolfram Mathematica or Geogebra? Then I can write that code in $\LaTeX$.

https://cmgreen.io/images/ahlfiter//conformal_example.png

this function on the picture

Comment: @user64494 no, I add picture what I mean.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
{fig1, fig2} = 
  With[{z = x + I*y}, 
     ParametricPlot[ReIm[#], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, Mesh -> 10, 
      PlotStyle -> LightGreen, 
      MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Darker[Green]], 
      BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.005], Darker[Green]], 
      Frame -> False, Axes -> False]] & /@ {z, z^2};
GraphicsRow[{fig1, fig2}]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much