# Solution this problem to illustrate the conformal mapping

Tags: plotting, complex, coordinate-transformation

Find the mapping of circle using confirmal mapping ( joukowski tansformation method)
Assume w= z+1/z
〖z=re〗^iθ = 〖r(cosθ+isinθ)〗^1   ( a Circle with radius r and center (0,0))

Comment: You might want to have a look at the answers here [`119516`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119516/plotting-an-equation-describing-a-joukowski-airfoil). Related threads are [`266643`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266643/illustrate-the-conformal-mapping), [`229505`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/229505/plotting-conformal-mappings-x-y-mapsto-x2-y), also [`244912`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/244912/how-can-i-display-conformal-mapping)

Comment: Please post the correct formula and symbol.

Comment: @bmf This probably could be migrated to math.SE. But we now have an example of what I will call the Conformal Elephant Method, as a posted solution to one of this spate of essentially identical do-my-homework questions. So it's easy just to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau ah yes. Nobody can forget about Ellie and her complex behavior patterns :)

Comment: @bmf Yes, Ellie does seem to be making the rounds. She may need to pack a trunk...

Comment: To the author of the OP, aside from the jokes that @DanielLichtblau and I are making about our favorite elephant, the first link I quoted discusses the same conformal mapping you want. The other posts are all related and of course Ellie is the Queen of the Mma.SE. Daniel, can we suggest to have Ellie sitting on the banner? :)

Comment: @bmf I don't think Ellie can afford to banner-sit for too long, what with all her globe trotting to display the wonders of conformal maps. I agree she should be some kind of icon though. "Ellie the Iconic, Tenth Wonder of the Modern World, Shows you the Secret Wonders of Complex Maps and the Astounding Mathematics of Conformal Elephant Method. Men Will Gasp and Women Will Swoon."

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I am keeping these priceless comments. I almost cried. Thank you. Now, back to refereeing a paper whilst thinking Ellie on the Math.S.E banner -I might try to answer a couple of questions more if the reviewing process gets too painful

Comment: @bmf You and me both. Mine is actually not refereeing but rather an AMS review for work already published. It is past due and I intend to finish it today. Of late it has hung over me like an ominous cloud. So yeah, today I actually do feel your pain.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau you have my mental support and I will be sending waves of strength and good vibes. With Ellie...on a rainbow

Comment: Likewise @bmf. Though maybe not Ellie on a rainbow, I'd be afraid she might get punctured by a unicorn or something.

Answer (score 10):

We can use `Manipulate` to find such suitable `Circle`.The circle through `{1,0}` and center by `w`(one possible `w={-.2, .4}`). The  Joukowsky tansformation mapping such circle to a closed curve like the wings of an airplane.

```
Manipulate[
 Block[{w = {1, I} . pt, r = Abs[w - 1], z = w + r*Exp[I*t]}, 
  GraphicsRow@{Graphics[{Circle[pt, r], Text[pt, pt], 
      AbsolutePointSize[5], {Red, Point[{1, 0}]}}, PlotRange -> 3, 
     Axes -> True], 
    ParametricPlot[ReIm[z + 1/z], {t, 0, 2 π}, 
     PlotRange -> 3]}], {{pt, {-.2, .4}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image]

*

```
Manipulate[
 Block[{w1, r1, z1, pt2, w2, r2, z2, t, c}, w1 = {1, I} . pt1; 
  r1 = Abs[w1 - 1]; z1 = w1 + r1*Exp[I*t];
  pt2 = (1 - c)*{1, 0} + c*pt1;
  w2 = {1, I} . pt2; r2 = Abs[w2 - 1]; z2 = w2 + r2*Exp[I*t];
  λ0 = 
   SolveValues[First[(1 - c)*{1, 0} + c*pt1] == 0 /. pt1 -> {-.2, .4},
      c][[1]];
  GraphicsRow@{ParametricPlot[{ReIm[z1], ReIm[z2]}, {t, 0, 
      2 π}, {c, λ, 1}, MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, 
     Mesh -> {{λ0}}, MeshStyle -> White, PlotRange -> 2, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
     Epilog -> {Point[pt1], Point[pt2 /. c -> λ], 
       Line[{pt1, pt2 /. c -> λ}], Dotted, 
       Line[{pt2 /. c -> λ, {1, 0}}]}, PlotStyle -> Magenta], 
    ParametricPlot[{ReIm[(z1 + 1/z1)/2], ReIm[(z2 + 1/z2)/2]}, {t, 0, 
      2 π}, {c, λ, 1}, MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, 
     Mesh -> {{λ0}}, MeshStyle -> White, PlotRange -> 2, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
     PlotStyle -> Magenta]}], {{pt1, {-.2, .4}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 
   1}}, {{λ, λ0}, 0, 1 - $MachineEpsilon}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image]

Comment: Really wonderful stuff!!!

Comment: @bmf Thanks your upvote! I don't know how to make the text and the graphics row looks good.

Comment: yes, it's a bit tricky as it would seem. but I have to say they don't look bad and things are very clear. if I manage to come up with something, I will leave a comment :)

Comment: update: some partial progress -not very satisfactory- can be made as follows: `Manipulate[Block[{w = pt[[1]] + pt[[2]]*I, r = Abs[pt[[1]] + pt[[2]]*I - 1], z = w + r*Exp[I*t]}, GraphicsRow@{Graphics[{Circle[pt, r], Text[pt, pt, {-2, -10}, {1, 0}], AbsolutePointSize[5], {Red, Point[{1, 0}]}}, PlotRange -> 3, Axes -> True], 
ParametricPlot[ReIm[z + 1/z], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> 3]}], {{pt, {-.2, .4}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}, ControlPlacement -> Top]` Did you have in mind something like that or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Upvoted, begrudgingly. I do not much like having responses to do-my-homework when no effort on the part of the poster is shown. But this is a nice answer all the same.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  Thanks! I am also vote to close the question since it missing details until I suddently find a way to catch the meaning :-)